# Formula for $P\small CO_2$

Tags: linear-algebra, chemistry

Not really sure where I was supposed to ask this question. I have no background/knowledge in chemistry or math of this level.

This is a follow-up question from my question over at StackOverflow ([question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28345621/converting-davenport-diagram)) regarding the Henderson-Hasselbalch equation and how implement in a web environment that uses $x$/$y$ coordinates for plotting.

I think reading the StackOverflow question will most likely clarify what I'm asking for specifically.

---

The Davenport Diagram in question: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dIi9e.jpg

Since the tool I use to plot it uses $X$ and $Y$ coordinates, would it be even possible to calculate the $P\small CO_2$ (red lines) value-based of the $HCO_3$ ($Y$ coordinate) and $pH$ ($X$ coordinate). I figure that it would need a custom-tailored formula (if it is even possible). $P\small CO_2$ is a constant in the Henderson-Hasselbalch equation.

I searched for it a whole lot, I am not sure if I was even searching correctly since the jargon used on all those sites makes no sense to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the formula [seems to be](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arterial_blood_gas#pH)

$$ pH = 6.1 + \log_{10} \left(\frac{HCO_3^{-}}{0.03 \times P_{co_2}}\right)$$

Hence

$$ P_{co_2}=\frac{HCO_3^{-}}{0.03} 10^{6.1-pH}  \approx  HCO_3^{-} \times 10^{7.623-pH}  $$

This seems to fit with your graph (eg: $HCO_3^{-}=16$, $pH=7.65$ $P_{co_2}=15.03$)

Comment: I seem to do something wrong, since the result you posted matches up with the graph. However, the equation for PCO2 just spews random stuff at me that aren't even close to the required results. The formula I got from your explanation is **(HCO3 / 0.03) + 10^(7.623 - pH)**, I'm probably messing something up.

Comment: I posted two formulas, pick one, your are mixing them -and adding a plus sign. The later is  HCO3 x 10^(7.623 - pH)

Comment: I was just using the correct one, however, the values were right. The values were in the hundreds, instead of the tenths. All I had to do was divide by 10 again to get the correct values. Marking your answer as correct.